# How to save the background colour to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm using a select box with font sizes and a colour picker to allow a user to select a preferred header background colour as well as the font size.

The font size is saving to the local storage as expected and updating when the page is re-visited (although I'd prefer it to be already changed rather than animating to the new size).

However, I've done the backfground colour the exact same way but when I change the colour, it works once but returns back to it's previous colour when the oage is re-opened.

HTML:

```
<header class="siteHeader">
            <div id="container">
                <select id="change_font_size">
                    <option value="225">225</option>
                    <option selected value="250">250</option>
                    <option value="300">300</option>
                    <option value="350">350</option>
                </select>
                <p style="float: left;">A+/-</p>
                <input type="color" id="colour_picker">
                <p style="float: right;">Background colour:</p>
                </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="burritos.html">BURRITOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var font_size = localStorage.getItem("font_size");
    $('.siteHeader').css("font-size", font_size + "%");
    var background_colour = localStorage.getItem("background_colour");
    $('.siteHeader').css("background-color", background_colour);

    $("#change_font_size").change(function () {
        var font_size = $(this).val();
        $('.siteHeader').css("font-size", font_size + "%");
        localStorage.setItem("font_size", font_size);
    });

    $('#colour_picker').change(function () {
        var background_colour = $(this).val();
        $('.siteHeader').css("background-color", background_colour);
        localStorage.setItem("background_color", background_colour);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting it as "background_color" and attempting to retrieve it as "background_colour".

Comment: Thank you @Mickers I've changed everything to the silly American way now to simplify things

Comment: Glad I could help :)